# How to set background color in multicolumn listview based on value in android?

Tags: java, android, json, android-listview, android-adapterview

I am new to android and I have one table in database and I want to change url using json parser and retrieve the program then output will come.

My question is how to change background color based on value ex (`quantity(qny)` is 0 to 10 the background color is red, 11 to 30 means background color is green, 31 to 50 means background color is blue).

code:

```
public class AndroidJSONParsingActivity extends ListActivity {


private static String url = "http://10.0.2.2:51382/RestServiceImpl.svc/json/123";

/* JSON Node names */
private static final String TAG_CONTACTS = "JSONDataResult";
private static final String TAG_ID = "Id";
private static final String TAG_NAME = "Name";

private static final String TAG_MRP = "Mrp";
private static final String TAG_QNT = "qty";

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    // Hashmap for ListView
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> contactList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

    // Creating JSON Parser instance
    JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();

    // getting JSON string from URL
    JSONObject json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(url);

    try {
        // Getting Array of Contacts
        JSONArray contacts = json.getJSONArray("JSONDataResult");


        // looping through All Contacts
        for(int i = 0; i < contacts.length(); i++){
            JSONObject c = contacts.getJSONObject(i);

            // Storing each json item in variable
            String Id = c.getString(TAG_ID);
            String Name = c.getString(TAG_NAME);
            //String email = c.getString("Age");
            String Mrp = c.getString(TAG_MRP);
            String qnt = c.getString(TAG_QNT);
        //  String address = c.getString(TAG_ADDRESS);
        //String gender = c.getString(TAG_GENDER);

            // creating new HashMap
            HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

            // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
            map.put(TAG_ID, Id);
            map.put(TAG_NAME, Name);
            map.put(TAG_MRP, Mrp);
            map.put(TAG_QNT, qnt);
            //map.put(TAG_PHONE_MOBILE, mobile);

            // adding HashList to ArrayList
        contactList.add(map);
        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


    /**
     * Updating parsed JSON data into ListView
     * */
    ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, contactList,
            R.layout.list_item,
            new String[] { TAG_ID, TAG_NAME, TAG_MRP,  TAG_QNT }, new int[] {
                    R.id.id, R.id.name, R.id.mrp, R.id.qnt });

    setListAdapter(adapter);
  }
}
```

Comment: you need customadapter class

Comment: @Stack Overflow User nope just overriding if u any suggestion means tell me

Comment: best way choose arrayadapter extended class on getview method check your condition and change layout background!

Comment: @StackOverflowUser oh thanks, any sample??

Answer (score 0):

just try this tutorial for it's change image dynamically using array adapter and check based on your condition mention layout change it's background.

http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-listview-example/